# Handling filesize AjaxControlToolkit AjaxUpload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-config

i want to print an error message but i couldn t pls help

here is the javascrpit which i found from somewhere on net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(sender, e) {
         var size = e.get_fileSize();
         if (size > 289496) {
             var err = new Error();
             err.name = 'My API Input Error';
             err.message = 'Filesize Error';
             throw (err);
         }
         else {
             var div = document.getElementById("status");
             div.innerHTML += "<p>uploaded: " + e.get_fileName() + "</p>";
         }
     }
    </script>
```

Ajax

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload
    id="AjaxUpload1"
    OnUploadComplete="AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete"
    MaximumNumberOfFiles="5"
    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
    ThrobberID="MyThrobber"
    runat="server" />

<asp:Image
       id="MyThrobber"
       ImageUrl="/images/indicator.gif"
       Style="display:none"
       runat="server" />
```

Code-behind

```
protected void AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "~/images/ajax/" + e.FileName;
        AjaxUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    }
```

webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="289496"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

upload works and filesize is ok but i want to print an error when user choosed a file bigger than the limit.

Answer (score 0):

first, the thing to remember, if you chose to upload a file larger than 'maxAllowedContentLength' it will break the application resulting in an error, could not quite remember the error code.

second, why don't you abandon the idea of a javascript function (on upload complete) and check the size in the codebehind OnUploadComplete and if not allowed then set a label text value to a "Incorrect size" string.

you would have something like this

in aspx

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="status" >
```

and in codebehind

```
        protected void AjaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
               {
                 if(e.FileSize > 289496){ //or something like that    
                 status.Text = "Incorrect size";
                                        }
    else{
                 string filePath = "~/images/ajax/" + e.FileName;
                 AjaxUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        }
              }
```

Comment: before i made exactly the same and but i didn t worked. it just stops the uploading and there is no error :S